# How to convert OffscreenCanvas to DataURI

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to do some drawing on OffscreenCanvas and then show it as a background-image of the div element.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest for you is to use the [OffscreenCanvas.convertToBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/convertToBlob), also known as *OffscreenCanvas.toBlob()* in Firefox.

As a rule of thumb, you don't want the dataURL version. Almost all you want to do with a dataURL should be done with a blobURL instead.
BlobUrls allow us to link to data that has to be stored only once in memory, whereas a dataURI will take 134% of the needed data everytime it appears as a string + 100% of the actual data everytime it will get fetched.

```js
(function() {
const worker = new Worker(generateWorkerURL());
worker.onmessage = e => {
  // generate a blobURI from the Blob
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(e.data.blob);
  // use it
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
};

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();

worker.postMessage({canvas: offscreen}, [offscreen]);

function generateWorkerURL() {
  const scr = document.querySelector('[type="worker-script"]');
  const cont = scr.textContent;
  const blob = new Blob([cont], {type: 'text/javascript'});
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
})();
```

```css
body{width: 100vw; height: 100vh; margin: 0}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  onmessage = e => {
    const canvas = e.data.canvas;
    // red squares 
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    gl.viewport(0, 0,
    gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
    gl.scissor(20, 20, 60, 60);

    gl.clearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // export as Blob
    (canvas.convertToBlob || canvas.toBlob).call(canvas)
    .then(blob => {
      postMessage({blob});
    });

  }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lo. Is it possible to do it without Worker?

Comment: @Valerii yes sure you can, but then why do you want to use an OffscreenCanvas at all?

Comment: I use canvas just to generate image so its not a visual element. I don't want to add it to the DOM. I think maybe using OffscreenCanvas will be more efficient?

Comment: No, using an HTMLCanvasElement taht you don't append to the document will do the same, with better browser support. OffscreeenCanvas is meant for context's where there is no DOM (i.e Workers)